# Protractor - scroll the page in Android

Tags: android, testing, protractor, appium

I am using Android Hybrid app for testing using Protractor.
I want to scroll the page in the app. I am using the ScrollTo or ScrollBy. It's  neither scrolling the Page nor giving any error, but its printing the text in the visible page.

Please help.

My Code is below:

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0,100000);').then(function() {
    element.all(by.css('.row.qcl-section-header')).getText().then( function(text) {
        console.log(text) 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [`getLocation()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getLocation) to get the x and y coordinates, then use `window.scrollTo()` to scroll:

```
element.all(by.css('.row.qcl-section-header')).getLocation().then(function(navDivLocation) {
    initTop = navDivLocation.y;
    initLeft = navDivLocation.x;
    browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(' + initTop + ',' + initLeft + ');').then(function() {
        element.all(by.css('.row.qcl-section-header')).getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log(text)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alecxe and rajana sekhar.   It is not Scrolling to that particular element. ScrollTo function is not working in Android device.   Is there any other way which we can scroll the page in Android device?